# Escaping regex expressions using Go Validator v2

Tags: regex, validation, go, struct

I'm currently using Go Validator.v2 (https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/validator.v2) to perform some data validation via the in-built regexp feature. The simple example given works correctly for me:

```
type NewUserRequest struct {
    SomeString string `validate:"min=3,max=40,regexp=^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`
}
nur := NewUserRequest{SomeString : "JamesBond"}
```

However, when I start to introduce complexity to the RegEx such as allowing multiple special characters (`_` or `-` or `.`) which require escaping (for validating an email or something), I start to encounter issues. I either get an "Unknown tag" error if I escape special characters with double slash`\\` or it will simply skip validation (any string will pass) if I use single slash `\`:

```
Input string: "James.Bond-007@email.co.uk"
regexp: `validate:"regexp=^[_A-Za-z0-9\\-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9\\-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"`
Expected result: PASS - valid string
Actual result/output: 'Unknown tag' error
```

```
Input string: "06/06/2006"
regexp: `validate:"regexp=^[_A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9\-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"`
Expected result: Invalid string
Actual result/output: PASS - Validation passed/skipped.
```

Anyone else having similar issues or can provide a way to escape regexp correctly using Go Validator.v2?

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: why are there backticks around  `validate:"min=3,max=40,regexp=^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`

Comment: Before: `validate:"regexp=\\\\"` after equals what ? Can you print out the regex after parsing ? What do the docs say about the language parsing. You have to get past that to before its handed to the regex engine. \\ ?

Comment: If you just want to test a regex, I guess if you just want to make the same regex without using escapes try this `^[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+([.][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+([.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*([.][A-Za-z]{2,})$`

Comment: @Maxt8r thanks for your comments, the backticks are there because it is the syntax for declaring tags within struct fields in GoLang. They're not part of the actual regex.

Comment: @Maxt8r thanks for the suggested regex without using escapes, I shall give that a try. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I actually find it hard to believe the comma needs a double escape. At most the language parser is going to rip a single escape off, leaving an escape behind for something else. No regex engine has a proclivity towards comma escaping that i know of except that if it _IS_ escaped, it is a literal. Therefore, `{2\,}` becomes a string of literals, not a braces quantifier. However in order to remove the last escape on the comma, the language has to remove the last escape on all the other double escaped literals. It can't be both ways, Either `{2,}` is handed to engine or `{2\,}` is.

Comment: Followup to my last comment. Lets test that quant brace literal theory using golang regex 
`[a-z]+\d{2\,}` 
https://regex101.com/r/TJOBth/1 We see it matches `abc8{2,}` It may be a bug, but there won't be a way to get correct quant braces to the engine without removing other double escapes as well. i.e `\\.[a-z]+\\d{2\\,}` would have to get `.[a-z]+d{2,}` to the engine.

Comment: Looking at it again, for example: `validate:"min=3,max=40,regexp=^\\s[a-zA-Z]{2\\,3}*$"` it is clear that the outer field `validate:`
is parsed via double quoted string `"..."` to get the value of validate object.
The result is this string `min=3,max=40,regexp=^\s[a-zA-Z]{2\,3}*$`
It is then parsed like a csv file using comma as the delimiter which is not what you would expect.
Because to imbedd a comma in a field usuaally means the field has to be quoted.
But they did not want to overkill since the double quote was already used to describe
the value of the object before.

Comment: Result is to embedd a comma in the field it has to be escaped.
The end is parsing of 3 csv fields `min=3` , `max=40` , `regexp=^\s[a-zA-Z]{2,3}*$`
Its a _very odd_ way of doing it ! If that is the design, (I'm sure it is), you just have to double escape all comma's no matter where they are, even inside classes as a literal or a range separator in quantifiers. Doesn't matter. And it wouldn't be considered a bug, but a bad design through. There are some command line engines that run script that have this problem as well.

Comment: You kind of would never know this looking at your sample as you only had one value within the _validate_, csv fields.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough investigation, you're right about how they parse each of the validation rules (comma separated), and hence the double backslashes ```\\``` is needed for ```,```, but I've also found that comma is not the only special char needed double backslashes, e.g. the ```.``` char also needed double backslashes.. strange indeed!

Comment: The regex should be created as if it were a Java quoted string. The added step is to double escape all commas in the regex.
It might be simpler to show you the steps they take to parse it.
**1:** [Parse out Validate double quote string](https://regex101.com/r/y1a2Uk/1)
**2:** [Un-Escape escapes](https://regex101.com/r/mcE4wZ/1)
**3:** [Get Array of Comma Sep Values](https://regex101.com/r/xgGy4n/1)
**4:** [Un-Escape CSV comma delimiter](https://regex101.com/r/CPYwVn/1)
I've reversed engineered this, it wasn't hard. Let me know if there are problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `go-validator/validator` ["Escape commas in regex" bug description](https://github.com/go-validator/validator/issues/57):

> You'll need to escape the comma with 2 backslashes.

You can fix your code like this:

```
regexp: `validate:"regexp=^[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2\\,})$"`
```

Note you do not need to escape a hyphen when it is at the final position inside a character class, and `+` does not have to be escaped there.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and suggestion! I also saw this issue on GitHub before, that's what prompted me to add double back slashes ```\\``` in front of literally all the special characters.. Thanks for clarifying that not all special characters needed escaping in my regex! Your suggested solution almost worked for me, I just needed to replace the single back slashes in front of the dots ```.``` with double back slashes (just as it is with the commas ```,```). If you edit that then I can accept your answer as the solution :) Cheers again!